# Правильный парсинг слов через Регулярные выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения

имеется слово "**какой-то**" в тексте. Из текста нужно удалить все знаки препинания, однако, если я использую такую конструкцию  `RegExp [\p{P}]`, то тире удаляется и из слова "**какой-то**". Подскажите пожалуйста, как поправить шаблон, чтобы правило было верным.

Comment: После знака препинания, если не ошибаюсь, может быть или же пробел, или другой знак препинания, или же окончание строки, но не "буква". Исходя из этого, можно попробовать такой вариант - `\p{P}(?=\P{L}|$)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А если на самом деле ты хотел не удалить, а разбить на слова, то это делается гораздо проще:

```js
var s = 'имеется слово "какой-то" в тексте. Из текста нужно удалить все знаки препинания, однако, если я использую такую конструкцию RegExp [\p{P}], то тире удаляется и из слова "какой-то". Подскажите пожалуйста, как поправить шаблон, чтобы правило было верным.'

console.log(s.match(/\p{L}+(-\p{L}+)*/gu))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Comment: Спасибо! Все варианты подходят!

Answer (score 0):

Вот 3 способа:

```js
var s = 'имеется слово "какой-то" в тексте. Из текста нужно удалить все знаки препинания, однако, если я использую такую конструкцию RegExp [\p{P}], то тире удаляется и из слова "какой-то". Подскажите пожалуйста, как поправить шаблон, чтобы правило было верным.'

console.log(s.replace(/(\p{L}-(?=\p{L}))|[^\s\p{L}]/gu, "$1"))
console.log(s.replace(/(?!(?<=\p{L})-\p{L})[^\s\p{L}]/gu, ""))
console.log(s.replace(/(?!-\p{L}(?<=\p{L}..))[^\s\p{L}]/gu, ""))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```